# I need information from one table to reflect a generated column in the other table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE FlockTot 
(Shed_num varchar(250) NOT NULL,
flocknum INT NOT NULL);

INSERT into FlockTot (Shed_num, flocknum)
Values 
('Shed1','2200'),
('Shed2','2100'),
('Shed3','2000'),
('Shed4','2500');

Create Table FlockChanges
(shed_num varchar(250) NOT NULL,
removed INT,
deceased INT,
total_reduced INT generated always as (removed+deceased) stored);

INSERT into FlockChanges (shed_num, removed, deceased)
Values 
('Shed1','1','2'),
('Shed2','3','4'),
('Shed3','2','2'),
('Shed4','5','5');
```

NOW I want to add a generated always column in FlockTot which is flocknum-totalreduced.

How do i do that?

Comment: Noway. Generated column cannot use subqueries. If this **really** needed (I doubt) then use trigger logic.

Comment: Hi Akina, thanks for replying, what is a trigger and how do I use that? Could you guide me please?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ai_update_FlockTot
AFTER INSERT 
ON FlockChanges
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE FlockTot SET new_col = flocknum - NEW.total_reduced;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c40a34e66c111ecb27d75223e972a4a

Comment: What if a row gets deleted? What if a row gets updated? That trigger alone cannot prevent data inconsistencies in such cases.

Comment: @stickybit You must create 2 additional triggers, after update and after delete, which do approx. the same.

Comment: Yeah, *I* know that (and that triggers aren't a good solution here anyway) but does the OP or any future reader with the same question? My comment was intended for them (or you to complete your answer with these triggers and an explanation and warning about such problems).

Comment: @stickybit The structure of `FlockChanges` assumes that the rows are added into only. If edition/deletion needed one more row which corrects the amounts is added. Another scheme seems to be illogical.

Answer (score 0):

Generated columns cannot access columns of other tables. But you can use a view. Assuming that `shed_num` is the primary key (or at least a key) in both tables something along the lines of:

```
CREATE VIEW flocktot_with_totalreduced
AS
SELECT ft.shed_num,
       ft.flock_num,
       ft.flock_num - coalesce(fc.total_reduced, 0) totalreduced
       FROM flocktot ft
            LEFT JOIN flockchanges fc
                      ON fc.shed_num = ft.shed_num;
```

If `shed_num` isn't a key you may additionally need some aggregation.

It seems however, that your design is flawed from the beginning. `flockchanges` should be the only materialized table with only **one** integer column for the change and another for the optional reason. To get the current total use a view aggregating over `flockchanges`.

```
CREATE TABLE flockchanges
             (id integer
                 AUTO_INCREMENT,
              shed_num varchar(250)
                       NOT NULL,
              change integer
                     NOT NULL,
              reason varchar(256),
              PRIMARY KEY (id));

INSERT INTO flockchanges
            (shed_num,
             change,
             reason)
            VALUES ('Shed1',
                    2200,
                    NULL),
                   ('Shed2',
                    2100,
                    NULL),
                   ('Shed3',
                    2000,
                    NULL),
                   ('Shed4',
                    2500,
                    NULL),
                   ('Shed1',
                    -1,
                    'Removed'),
                   ('Shed1',
                    -2,
                    'Deceased'),
                   ('Shed2',
                    -3,
                    'Removed'),
                   ('Shed2',
                    -4,
                    'Deceased'),
                   ('Shed3',
                    -2,
                    'Removed'),
                   ('Shed4',
                    -3,
                    'Deceased'),
                   ('Shed1',
                    -5,
                    'Removed'),
                   ('Shed4',
                    -5,
                    'Deceased');

CREATE VIEW flocktot
AS 
SELECT shed_num,
       sum(change) flocknum
       FROM flockchanges
       GROUP BY shed_num;
```

Remember that relational tables aren't spreadsheets, so **don't** try using them like spreadsheets!

And by the way, you don't need and should not quote numeric literals.

Comment: Hi Sticky Bit, I think your are correct, this needs to be changed fundamentally - what would eventually happen is I would not be inputting these values- they would be coming through a data collection tool Device Magic forms. And then I would just want all of it to aggregate together.